# ServiceStack.Text reading json results not working

Tags: json, vb.net, servicestack, json-deserialization, servicestack-text

I am just trying to figure out the best way to deserialize a json string returned from a 3rd party api call.   I read ServiceStack is fast so want to try it out.  No experience and here is what I have done:

1. Opened Visual Studio 2013
2. Created new project Windows Forms Application
3. Installed ServiceStack.Text (based on https://servicestack.net/download)
4. Added a button (btnView) and textbox (txtOutput)
5. Add code to btnView_Click event

   ```
          Private Sub btnView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnView.Click

       Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

       Dim wp As New WebPost 'this allows to pass url and return results
       wp.URL = "xxxx"
       Dim sJSONRetVal As String = wp.Request(String.Empty, True)
   'sJSONRetVal return values looks like the following:
   '{"complaints":[{"feedback_type":"abuse","subject":"Sales Agent Position"},{"feedback_type":"abuse","subject":"Sales Agent Position"}],"message":"OK","code":0}


       'ServiceStack.Text example
       Dim t As SMTP_Complaints = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(Of SMTP_Complaints)(sJSONRetVal)

       'For Each xi As SMTP_Complaints In t
       '    txtOutput.Text &= xi.mail_from & vbCrLf
       'Next

       wp = Nothing

       txtOutput.Text = t.ToString

       Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default

   End Sub

   Public Class SMTP_Complaints

   Dim _feedback_type As String = ""
   Dim _subject As String = ""

   Public Property feedback_type As String
       Get
           Return _feedback_type
       End Get
       Set(value As String)
           _feedback_type = value
       End Set
   End Property

   Public Property subject As String
       Get
           Return _subject
       End Get
       Set(value As String)
           _subject = value
       End Set
   End Property
   End Class
   ```

The above doesn't seem to get any data.  how would I loop through the data returned and return the data from both instances?  Just not sure how I need to set this up to read the json data and then be able to output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the returned JSON of:

```
{"complaints":[{"feedback_type":"abuse","subject":"Sales Agent Position"},{"feedback_type":"abuse","subject":"Sales Agent Position"}],"message":"OK","code":0}
```

You will need two DTOs to deserialise this result.

*I have used [auto implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd293589.aspx) here to simplify the complexity of the code. If you use an older version of VB, you'll need to expand these out to include a backing field with get and set method.*

```vb
Public Class SMTP_Complaint
    Public Property feedback_type As String
    Public Property subject As String
End Class

Public Class SMTP_ComplaintsResponse
    Public Property complaints As SMTP_Complaint()
    Public Property message As String
    Public Property code As Integer
End Class
```

You need the `SMTP_ComplaintsResponse` class because your complaints are wrapped in your JSON response.

Then to deserialise the response:

```
Dim response = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(Of SMTP_ComplaintsResponse)(sJSONRetVal)
```

And your complaints are then accessible:

```
For Each complaint As var In response.complaints
    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}, Subject {1}", complaint.feedback_type, complaint.subject)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Scott.  That's beautiful!  Worked like a charm.  Appreciate your time and info.

Comment: @user1167215 You're welcome. Glad it worked. Good luck with your project.